# Deltaspike Data (CDI + JPA) Custom PrePersistAuditListener and PreUpdateAuditListener for custom java.time.ChronoLocalDateTime at UTC

Tags: cdi, weld, deltaspike, weld2, deltaspike-jpa

> Deltaspike Ver 1.7.2 on Wildfly 9.0.2.Final

I'm using the JPA `@EntityListeners(AuditEntityListener.class)` and the audit functionality of Deltaspike Data (`@CreatedOn`, `@ModifiedOn` and `@ModifiedBy` annotations) on an entity bean with the difference that I have a custom implementation of `java.time.ChronoLocalDateTime` which converts any `LocalDateTime` + `ZoneOffset` OR a `ZonedDateTime` to be the UTC date & time.

#### UTCDateTime

```
public class UTCDateTime implements ChronoLocalDateTime<LocalDate>, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6492792765662073566L;
  private static final ZoneOffset UTC = ZoneOffset.UTC;
  private final LocalDateTime datetime;

  // a lot of other details left out
}
```

#### The entity bean parts

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class InsertableAuditableBean extends BaseBean implements InsertableAuditable {

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
  @Column(name = "zz_inserted_by", length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String insertedBy;

  @CreatedOn
  @NotNull
  @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "zz_inserted_on", nullable = false)
  private UTCDateTime insertedOn;

  // getters & setters
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class UpdateableAuditableBean extends InsertableAuditableBean implements UpdateableAuditable {

  @ModifiedBy
  @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
  @Column(name = "zz_updated_by", length = 50, nullable = true)
  private String updatedBy;

  @ModifiedOn
  @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "zz_updated_on", nullable = true)
  private UTCDateTime updatedOn;

  // getters & setters
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditEntityListener.class)
@Table(schema = "data", name = "manufacturer", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "man_name", "man_country" })
})
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "primaryKey", column = @Column(name = "man_serial")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "insertedBy", column = @Column(name = "man_inserted_by")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "insertedOn", column = @Column(name = "man_inserted_on")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "updatedBy", column = @Column(name = "man_updated_by")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "updatedOn", column = @Column(name = "man_updated_on"))
})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_seq", schema = "data", sequenceName = "manufacturer_man_serial_seq",
    allocationSize = 1)
public class Manufacturer extends MirroredUpdateableAuditableBean implements IManufacturer {
  // nothing special here
}
```

There is also a custom AttributeConverter for the UTCDateTime class because the epoch value is saved in the database.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UTCDateTimePersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter<UTCDateTime, Long> {

  @Override
  public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(final UTCDateTime entityValue) {
    Long res = null;
    if (entityValue != null) {
      res = entityValue.toMillis();
    }
    return res;
  }

  @Override
  public UTCDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Long databaseValue) {
    UTCDateTime res = null;
    if (databaseValue != null) {
      res = new UTCDateTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli(databaseValue));
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Now when I persist the entity I get the following exception (the last bit with the real cause):

```
Caused by: org.apache.deltaspike.data.api.QueryInvocationException: Failed calling Repository: [Repository=systems.apace.data.manufacturer.model.dao.ManufacturerDAO,entity=systems.apace.data.manufacturer.model.Manufacturer,method=persist,exception=class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException,message=null
        at systems.apace.data.manufacturer.services.ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.testInsertBean(ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at systems.apace.data.manufacturer.services.ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.testInsertBean(ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.AuditPropertyException: Failed to set property Manufacturer.insertedOn, is this a temporal type?
        at systems.apace.data.manufacturer.services.ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.testInsertBean(ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotated field is not a date class: class za.co.t9.common.utils.time.UTCDateTime
        at systems.apace.data.manufacturer.services.ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.testInsertBean(ManufacturerServiceBeanIntegrationTest.java:55)
```

Is there a way to implement my own `org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.PrePersistAuditListener` and `org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.PreUpdateAuditListener` and use them to create the instance of `UTCDateTime`?

Would it be correct to write my own EntityListener --> `UTCDateTimeAuditListener` and use it `@EntityListeners(UTCDateTimeAuditEntityListener.class)` where `UTCDateTimeAuditListener` follows the `org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.AuditEntityListener` approach?

Secondly, do I need to use a CDI Qualifier somewhere to make sure that my `UTCDateTimeAuditEntityListener` gets a reference to the correct `PrePersistAuditListener` and `PreUpdateAuditListener` implementations that know how to construct the `UTCDateTime` instance?

Lastly, I don't know if it is relevant, but where does `org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider` fit into this scenario?

### Update

I have made some progress in answering my questions. What I have done so far.
There is no need for a custom `AuditEntityListener` the one supplied by DeltaSpike is sufficient.

I created a new implementation of the `TimestampsProvider` that is capable of handling my `UTCDateTime` objects.

```
@Alternative
@Dependent
public class UTCDateTimeAuditProvider implements PrePersistAuditListener, PreUpdateAuditListener {
  // implementation details not important
}
```

The beans.xml also list this as an CDI @Alternative

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

  <alternatives>
    <class>systems.apace.data.manufacturer.model.UTCDateTimeAuditProvider</class>
  </alternatives>
</beans>
```

Content of `apache-deltaspike.properties`

```
globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy=org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ContainerManagedTransactionStrategy
```

The problem now is that both `AuditProvider` instances are executed, first my implementation (`UTCDateTimeAuditProvider`) and then the default `TimestampsProvider`

```
2016-12-13 01:29:22,929 INFO  Apace-BPS s.a.d.m.m.UTCDateTimeAuditProvider [ServerService Thread Pool -- 319] [Unknown Id] - prePersist: class systems.apace.data.manufacturer.model.UTCDateTimeAuditProvider
2016-12-13 01:29:22,931 INFO  Apace-BPS s.a.d.m.m.UTCDateTimeAuditProvider [ServerService Thread Pool -- 319] [Unknown Id] - Updated property Manufacturer.insertedOn with 2016-12-12T23:29:22.930
2016-12-13 01:29:22,932 INFO  Apace-BPS z.c.t.c.b.e.EntityManagerProducer [ServerService Thread Pool -- 319] [Unknown Id] - username of Principal: anonymous
2016-12-13 01:29:22,932 FINER [org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.AuditProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 319) Updated Manufacturer.updatedBy with anonymous
2016-12-13 01:29:22,935 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 319) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."bpsserver.ear"."systems-apace-data-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.ManufacturerSi
ngleton.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."bpsserver.ear"."systems-apace-data-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.ManufacturerSingleton.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed
 to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
...
Caused by: org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.AuditPropertyException: Failed to set property Manufacturer.insertedOn, is this a temporal type?
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider.setProperty(TimestampsProvider.java:86)
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider.updateTimestamps(TimestampsProvider.java:67)
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider.prePersist(TimestampsProvider.java:43)
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.AuditEntityListener.persist(AuditEntityListener.java:42)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotated field is not a date class: class za.co.t9.common.utils.time.UTCDateTime
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider.now(TimestampsProvider.java:115)
        at org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.audit.TimestampsProvider.setProperty(TimestampsProvider.java:79)
        ... 115 more
```

I have tried various combinations of specifying my @Alternative implementation with only the annotation, or only in the beans.xml and both on the class & in beans.xml.

Does anyone know why the default `TimestampsProvider` gets executed after my @Alternative implementation?

> Deltaspike Ver 1.7.2 on Wildfly 9.0.2.Final with Weld 2.2.16 (SP1)

Comment: I have raised an issue with Deltaspike to enable @Alternative to be used for creating a custom implementation - (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-1229)

Answer (score 0):

Deltaspike data Audit does not support Java 8 Date and Time API.
You can combine @PrePersist, @PreUpdate methods with Deltaspike @ModifiedBy field into one common ancestor for all auditable entities (benefit: no need for a custom way of getting principal name).